# how to draw symmetrical line to the polygon?

Tags: geometry, shapefile, geotools, jts

I have a road polygon that I need to divide in given lanes. So I get a JTS geometry of roads from shapefile and I need to create lines or basically create a geometry lines (lanes) within that polygon. Something like this

[image]

The more complex scenarios are when roads are not straight for e.g.

[image]

So I need to create lanes within that polygon as the polygon lines go. Is it possible to get those lane/line geometries using JTS geometry functions?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** no.

I wrote a blog entry a while ago about how to [add "CenterLines" to polygons](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/2021/08/30/Skeletons.html) and it was not nearly as easy as I expected. That [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/unsupported/process-geometry/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/geometry/CenterLine.java) may be enough to get you started. Feel free to ask for advice on the [GeoTools users list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/geotools-gt2-users).